# Issue calling stored procedure

Tags: database, sql-server-2005, stored-procedures, coldfusion

I have a question about stored procedure which is created on windows sql server 2005. I have ColdFusion code to call the procedure. The first time I tried, it failed because the procedure didn't have the right permissions, so I added a new user which is `db_owner` and added to the procedure and then it ran properly.

But then I noticed that something wrong in the DB. My question is that even though I saw the error, do you think the procedure already start running? 
and it's stopped improperly (probably no necessary parameters, failed to reach out to each tables?), because of the permission issue? Also do you think it possibly causes DB crash as well?

---

```
<cftry>
    <cfstoredproc procedure="test" datasource="test" result="proc_results">
        <cfprocparam cfsqltype="cf_sql_varchar" variable ="A" value="#GetToken(form.test_A)#">
        <cfprocparam cfsqltype="cf_sql_varchar" variable ="B" value="#GetToken(form.test_B)#">
    </cfstoredproc>
    <cfcatch type="any">
        Error!
    </cfcatch>
</cftry>
```

---

Comment: Bottom line, you need to provide more information before anyone can answer your question. *something wrong in the DB* Specifically what went wrong? As mentioned below, you need dump the actual error - not just print "Error!" *RE: do you think the procedure already start running* That depends on the type of error that occurred. Dump the error and [edit your question](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/19306881/edit) to include the full error message.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A stored procedure error will not generally crash an entire database unless it is doing some very unorthodox things.  Databases such as SQL Server are designed to prevent such occurrences.

As to whether the stored procedure started running: When you tried to start it without the correct permissions, it would not have started.  If you say that it "ran properly" when you added the correct permissions, then it started.  It would depend on the particulars of the stored procedure as to whether it actually did anything or changed anything, or exited without error and without doing anything.

You would need to provide the code of the stored procedures and the relevant portions of the database structure before anyone could say with any certainty.

Answer (score 1):

Trying dumping out some of the details of the error:

```
<cfcatch>
<cfoutput>
    #cfcatch.message#   
    #cfcatch.detail#
</cfoutput>
</cfcatch>
```

Or even

```
<cfcatch>
   <cfdump var="#cfcatch#">
<cfcatch>
```